# How to enable cert auth for a web app which is hosted in Tomcat that connect to IIS

Tags: tomcat, authentication, iis, ssl-certificate, config

I have a web app which is hosted in Tomcat, and then tomcat is connect to IIS via a connector (Apache Tomcat Connector).

I would like to enable certificate authentication only to this web app. I have tried that enabling CLIENT-CERT in this webapp. It works fine without IIS. But when I tried to access from IIS, it doesn't have the prompt like accessing from tomcat to allow me to select client certificate and returned me a 401 right away.

I probably went to the wrong way. I am thinking is that true that I still need to config IIS in order to use this feature? but if I do so, how can I set this cert auth only to one web application since the tomcat connector for IIS is acted like one site folder (if I understood correctly)?

Or is there anyway that I can config the connector to send cert auth request to client?

Thanks in advance.
-Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I should use the URL-rewrite (reverse proxy) in IIS to forward the request to Tomcat instead of using the connector, and then I can enable IIS Client Certificate Authentication on IIS to implement this purpose. In this way, things are easier.